# Is it possible to send premium-only custom emojis with a Telegram Client?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegraf, telegram-api

Recently, Telegram released a new feature - Custom Emojis. They instantly became available to users, but there are no instructions on how to send them using a Telegram bot. Is it even possible within the API? And specifically on Telegraf?

Answer (score 1):

[This update](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#august-12-2022) describes methods that may be useful to you. I haven't tested them myself yet, but I think this is what is needed. I will write about the results as soon as I test it myself.